# I am trying to add two numbers in BCD. How do I go about adding the two hex values bit by bit with a carry?

Tags: assembly, arm, keil

I load two hex values in R0 and R1. I then have R2 set as the register where my sum should end up. How do I go about adding these hex values bit by bit? I am trying to pass in the two numbers to add as well as the location to store the result. Then Store the result in ram and pass back that address as well as passing back a 0 if no overflow occurred and a 1 if there was an overflow.

This is in ARM assembly

```
AREA mydata,DATA
SUM     DCD 0
        AREA mycode,CODE
        THUMB
        EXPORT __main
NUM1    DCD     0x275
NUM2    DCD     0x963
__main  PROC
        LDR R0,=NUM1    
        LDR R0,[R0]     ;R0 has NUM1
        LDR R1,=NUM2        
        LDR R1,[R1]     ;R1 has NUM2
        LDR R2,=SUM     
        LDR R2, [R2]    ;R2 has SUM 
        BL  adder
exit    B exit
        ENDP
adder   PROC
        BX LR   ;branch and exchange instruction set LR holds the return address  
        ENDP
        END
```

Comment: please describe in words perhaps with data values what the algorithm task you are after, input, manipulation, and result.

Comment: I have added the new information

Comment: it's not clear what you mean by BCD. Usually "BCD" means one value 0-9 per 8 bits, i.e. 0x01020309, then there's "packed BCD" which does use only one nibble (4 bits) per digit ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal#BCD_in_electronics ). In both cases you can add two BCD values by doing binary `add` with them, and then you have to resolve digits which did overflow, i.e. their sum was above/equal to 10. In such case you need to add another 6 at that digit place, to fix the result. (7+7 = 14 ; overflow and result is invalid digit 0xE ; 14+6 = 20 = 0x14 = packed BCD 14 = corrected)

Comment: There're certainly somewhere described tricks how to detect overflown digits elegantly even with CPU which don't have direct support for BCD math (x86 does have special instructions checking the value and correcting it, like http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/DAA.html, but I can't recall (after ~15 years) anything like that for ARM, so you should check yourself) But google in such case your best friend, there's no reason to reinvent the wheel (in this particular case).